# How do i fetch text from <span> tag for each row

Tags: selenium

how do i fetch some of text from each row.
Here is the code:::

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style =" "         > 
                <span calss=xxx'>Manager </span>
            </td>
            <td> 123</td>
            <td> 456 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style =" "         > 
                <span calss=xxx'>Employee </span>
            </td>
            <td> 123</td>
            <td> 456 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style =" "         > 
                <span calss=xxx'>Admin </span>
            </td>
            <td> 123</td>
            <td> 456 </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style =" "         > 
                <span calss=xxx'>Non-Admin </span>
            </td>
            <td> 123</td>
            <td> 456 </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

When i am clicking on one of rows out of 21 rows, its open one popup and that contain table having 3-4 rows.
One popup may contain 4 or 3 or 2 or 1 rows and so on.
I want to fetch that text(Manager, Employee, Admin,Non-Admin) for each row, After clicking on each row.
Found all the elements,
 @FindBy(xpath="//td[contains(text(),'Manager')]")
WebElement managerText;   but how do i perform actions on it.
The final output should be  something like as follow:
On first popup , 3 text(td) are there, should fetch and should display as follow:
Manager
Employee
Admin
On second popup , 2 texts(td) are there, should fetch and display 
Employee
Admin
For third pop up, only one td(text
Non-Admin.

With the help of getText() able to fetch the value and putting in loop if one of the text is not present on popup, its failing the script. Don't know how to handle No such element exception for all 21 rows or with looping command.
If any one knows, reply. Thanks.

Comment: The way you have written it's hard to read. Please simplify.

Comment: In short, 21 rows(table tag for each) are there, Say clicked on first row, popup will get open and showing only 2 options Manager & Employee, when clicked on second row, popup got displayed and showing  3 options Manager & Employee & Admin staff, Wanted to fetch those text(Manager, Employee etc.). Max to max 4 text (options) can be there.Not required popup code. Just want how do i fetch those text, if all 4 text(option) are not there should not fail the script.

Comment: @FindBy(xpath="//td[contains(text(),'Manager')]")
WebElement managerText;    and so on for all 4 options                                                                                                                                        for(int i=0; i<=NoOfDivs; i++) //This giving me 21 rows
  { clickOnAllMeasureListOneAfterOther.get(i).click(); 
   String text =managerText.getText();//which gives me word 'Manager'  and so on}

Comment: Now how do i write code which fetch Manger and all texts, if not all 4 texts are there  on popup should not fail the script. Whatever of number of texts are there should display on console from popup for all 21 rows.                      if(text.contains(null)) {
    
   }else {
    System.out.println(text);
   } something like i tried but not getting what to write in case of if(). Just wanted to print the text on console what popup contains 2 or 3 or 4 text. I hope above explanation may help you to understand my question. Please anybody knows, reply. Thanks.

Comment: On following code just wanted to add some code which make sure , is text not available should not display and continue ahead, script should not get fail.                List<WebElement> OB=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//td/span[contains(text(), ' ')]")));
          for(int j=1;j<OB.size();j++)
          {
           
              System.out.println(LOB.get(1).getText());
          }

Comment: See, there are 21 rows, so when you click on first row (a pop will be visible with some options) now you click somewhere to close the pop up and click on 2nd row to see the pop up , right ?